# Strange result from GDAL in python from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, gdal, arcgis-pro

I am in the process of converting my Desktop scripts to be Pro compatable, one script uses GDAL to calculate a sum of overlapping rasters generated previously in the script (because Cell Statistics always fails - Desktop and Pro); the changes in this script are limited to the `print()` statements. The code is run in a CMD window using propy, [as instructed in the ArcGIS Pro help docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm). I suspect that it may be an issue with NumPy, because the areas that don't overlap are appearing, but am at a loss as to where to even start trying to troubleshoot.

```
MosaicDataset = Driver.Create(OutRaster,MosaicWidth,MosaicHeight,1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
MosaicBand    = MosaicDataset.GetRasterBand(1)

MosaicDataset.SetGeoTransform(MosaicGT)
MosaicBand.Fill(0.0)           # fill with zeros
MosaicBand.FlushCache()        # and make sure it's written to the file
MosaicBand.SetNoDataValue(0.0) # set the NoData to zero

max = len(FilesToProcess)
print( 'Ingesting {} files'.format(max))
for ThisRaster in FilesToProcess: # Generated rasters are uncompressed GeoTIFF 
    print('Ingesting {}'.format(ThisRaster))
    ThisDS    = gdal.Open(ThisRaster,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    ThisGT    = ThisDS.GetGeoTransform()
    ThisRows  = ThisDS.RasterYSize
    ThisCols  = ThisDS.RasterXSize
    OffsetX   = int((ThisGT[0]-MosaicGT[0])/CellSize) # calculate the offset for this raster
    OffsetY   = int((MosaicGT[3]-ThisGT[3])/CellSize)
    # Read the whole input raster
    ThisBit   = ThisDS.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0,0,ThisCols,ThisRows) 
    # Read the matching block in the mosaic
    MosaicBit = MosaicBand.ReadAsArray(OffsetX,OffsetY,ThisCols,ThisRows)  
    # this is supposed to sum the arrays and write it back
    MosaicBand.WriteArray(numpy.add(MosaicBit,ThisBit),OffsetX,OffsetY)    
    ThisDS = None # Close the raster properly
```

This is the result (background values are -inf):
[image: The result from running in ArcGIS Pro]

The expected result when run using python 2.7 with ArcGIS Desktop:
[image: The correct result, when run in Desktop]

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong or the functions have changed from python 2.7 to 3.x?

Comment: Likely irrelevant, but can you check number of processors involved. I found some crazy results when Arc uses them all on some spatial analyst tools.

Comment: @FelixIP how do I check that? Is it just the geoprocessing environment parallel processing?

Comment: Yes, this is how I do it.. You might also check number of services running in resources monitor thingy