# Modify a subset of a raster based on a shapefile

Tags: python, raster, osgeo

I want to modify a subset of a raster based on the extent of a shapefile.
The raster is of ground elevations and I need to modify an area that has been excavate into a big hole by subtracting 200 m.

I was able to modify a square of the raster using this code but because it is based on the bounding box of the shapefile, the area modified does not follow the contours of the shapefile (which is irregular shaped).

How can I modify based on the shapefile extent?

Maybe I need a function that loops through all the pixels in the raster and if they are within the shapefile, add them to a list or something.

This is my code. I can add the raster and shapefile if required.

```
## code to modify the rasters - subtract elevation from site area
   from osgeo import gdal, ogr, gdalconst

# Define the path to your raster and shapefile
raster_path = smooth_DEM_path
shapefile_path = r"C:\WORK_FILES\Shapefiles\WA519        
Boundary.shp"
# Open raster dataset
raster_ds = gdal.Open(raster_path, gdalconst.GA_Update)

# Open shapefile and get the extent
shapefile_ds = ogr.Open(shapefile_path)
shapefile_layer = shapefile_ds.GetLayer()
extent = shapefile_layer.GetExtent()                                           

# Read the raster data
raster_band = raster_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
raster_data = raster_band.ReadAsArray()

# Get the geotransform data
geotransform = raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()

# Modify the area within the shapefile
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = extent
col_offset = int((xmin - raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()[0]) / raster_ds.GetGeoTransform() 
[1])   # minimum value of shapefile - (xorigin / pixel size)
row_offset = int((ymin - raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()[3]) / raster_ds.GetGeoTransform() 
[5]) 
col_extent = int((xmax - xmin) / raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()[1])           
row_extent = int((ymax - ymin) / raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()[5])              

print("------------------------------")
print("X origin:", geotransform[0])
print("Y origin:", geotransform[3])
print('Pixel size (width & height): %s %s' %(geotransform[1], geotransform[5]))
print("Total number of columns in raster:", raster_ds.RasterXSize)
print("Total number of rows in raster:", raster_ds.RasterYSize)
print('Number of columns in subset defined by shapefile: %s' %(col_extent))
print('Number of rows in subset defined by shapefile: %s' %(row_extent))
print('Number of columns from left edge of raster to left edge of shapefile %.2f' % 
(col_offset))
print('Number of rows from top edge of raster to top edge of shapefile %.2f' % 
(row_offset))

# Modify the subset of the raster data
subset = raster_data[20208:27774, 16500:9324].copy()     # row_offset+row_extent , 
col_offset+col_extent                  

# Set all values in the copied subset to -200
subset[:] = -200

# Add the modified subset back to the original array
raster_data[20208:27774, 16500:9324] += subset                                 

# Plot the masked subset of the raster data
plt.figure()
masked_data = np.ma.masked_where(raster_data == -9999, raster_data)
plt.imshow(masked_data, cmap='terrain')  # Change the colormap as needed
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Modified Raster Subset with Masked -9999 Values')
plt.xlabel('Column')
plt.ylabel('Row')
plt.show()

# Write the modified data back to the raster
raster_band.WriteArray(raster_data, xoff=col_offset, yoff=row_offset)
```

Comment: Qick and simple method: Rasterize your polygon to the same extent and cell size as the raster you want to modify, write 0's to your rasterized polygon and use 200 for burn value. From there read small chunks, to keep memory usage down, from both rasters with ReadAsArray, modify with numpy.subtract() and write the array back. If you're more confident with your skills have a look at my unanswered question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475985/strange-result-from-gdal-in-python-from-arcgis-pro where I read small rasters and modify a large raster, addition in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rasterio:

```
from rasterio import features
import rasterio, os
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

workspace = r"C:/GIS/data/dem_folder"
out_file = os.path.join(workspace, "modified_dem.tif")
demraster = os.path.join(workspace, "nh_72_6.tif")

dem_dataset = rasterio.open(fp=demraster, mode="r") #Read the input DEM
dem_array = dem_dataset.read(1) #Read the data as an array

#Read the shape using GeoPandas and create an array with the same shape as the dem_array,
#  where the values are False inside the polygon(s) and True outside them
shape_dataframe = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\GIStest\hole.shp") 
mask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask(geometries=shape_dataframe.geometry, out_shape=dem_array.shape,
                                transform=dem_dataset.transform)
mask = np.where(mask==False, -200, 0) #From True/False to 0/-200

modified_dem_array = dem_array+mask #Add the original dem and the mask to subtract 200 from the DEM inside the polygon(s)

#Save the modified array to file
with rasterio.open(fp=out_file, mode="w", driver=dem_dataset.driver, width=modified_dem_array.shape[1],
                   height=modified_dem_array.shape[0], count=1, crs=dem_dataset.crs, 
                   transform=dem_dataset.transform, dtype=modified_dem_array.dtype, 
                   compression="LZW") as dest:
    dest.write(modified_dem_array, 1)

del(dem_dataset) #Remove any locks on the input dem
```

[image]